# call step variable from main yml file using template

Tags: azure-devops

I am using yaml pipeline with azureDevops

I am try to use variable type step in my template

Below is my template file build.yml

```
parameters:
  - name: dotnetrestore
    type: step
    default:
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: dotnet restore
        inputs:
          command: restore
          projects: "**/*.csproj"
```

Is it possible to call this step variable from my main pipeline

For example here this example is doing within the same file. Below example i got from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse

```
parameters:
- name: myString
  type: string
  default: a string
- name: myMultiString
  type: string
  default: default
  values:
  - default
  - ubuntu
- name: myNumber
  type: number
  default: 2
  values:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 4
  - 8
  - 16
- name: myBoolean
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: myObject
  type: object
  default:
    foo: FOO
    bar: BAR
    things:
    - one
    - two
    - three
    nested:
      one: apple
      two: pear
      count: 3
- name: myStep
  type: step
  default:
    script: echo my step
- name: mySteplist
  type: stepList
  default:
    - script: echo step one
    - script: echo step two

trigger: none

jobs: 
- job: stepList
  steps: ${{ parameters.mySteplist }}
- job: myStep
  steps:
    - ${{ parameters.myStep }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course we can use single task as [step template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#insert-a-template). My start.yml is below.

```
parameters:
- name: dotnetrestore # the name of the parameter
  type: step # data type is Step
  default: 
    task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet restore
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: "**/*.csproj"

steps:
  - ${{ parameters.dotnetrestore }}
```

We can call this step variable from my main pipeline.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- template: start.yml
- script: echo step two
```

**Update**>>If you want to use dotnetcore step parameter in my main pipeline.
The start.yml is below.

```
parameters:
- name: dotnetrestore # the name of the parameter
  type: step # data type is Step
  default: 
    script: echo This is default steps

steps:
  - ${{ parameters.dotnetrestore }}
```

We can specify parameter for this step variable from main pipeline.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- template: start.yml
  parameters:
    dotnetrestore:
      task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: dotnet restore
      inputs:
        command: restore
        projects: "**/*.csproj"
- script: echo step two
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here you are using the stage parameter  in star.yml. can I use dotnetcore step parameter in my main pipeline. Because here you are just calling just start.yml.  I mean you declare the parameter on start.yml ane use at main pipeline.

Comment: Hi Vipin, I have updated the answer so you could use dotnetcore step parameter in main pipeline. Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks Edward. Here you are replacing the parameter in the main pipeline. Can I just call It in main pipeline without replacing. So that it can invoke the step written in start.yml?

Comment: Yeah, you could write the dotnetcore step directly in start.yml like my first example, so you could just call the start.yml in main pipeline without replacing.

Comment: Yes . This was my question. Thanks